# How to write a std::queue with a thread which only executes the "newest unexecuted task" from the queue?

Tags: queue, c++17, condition-variable, stdthread

I need to create a `std::queue` of tasks which is executed by a thread which is *only executing the latest task from the list*.

The tasks are let's say for example file copy tasks. But here is the important part. I don't have to always run through the whole queue of tasks. I just want to execute the latest unexecuted task from the queue and empty the queue right after popping out the task to execute. You see this part can be tricky. I have to be careful to not clear the queue with an unexecuted task pending :-)

**Following is the complete code:**

```
#include <atomic>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

using CopyTask = std::function<void(void)>;

class TaskQueue {
public:
    ~TaskQueue() {
        StopThread();
    }

    void CopyTaskCompleted() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> que_lock(m_push_mutex);
        m_trigger = true;
        que_lock.unlock();
        m_condition_variable.notify_one();
        std::cout << " CopyTaskCompleted called " << std::endl;
    }

    void PushCopyTask(CopyTask task) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_push_mutex);
        std::cout << " PushCopyTask called " << std::endl;

        if (!m_thread.joinable()) {
            StartThreadLooper();
            task();
            return;
        }

        if (!m_queue.empty()) {
            m_queue.push(task);
        } else {
            // If the queue is empty then there are no pending tasks. Simply run the task without posting it on the queue
            task();
        }
    }

private:
    std::queue<CopyTask> m_queue;
    std::mutex m_queue_mutex;
    std::mutex m_push_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_condition_variable;
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::atomic<bool> m_running {false};
    bool m_trigger {false};

    void StartThreadLooper() {
        m_running = true;
        std::cout << " Looper thread going to start " << std::endl;
        m_thread = std::thread( [this] {
            while (m_running) {
                std::cout << " Looper thread running " << std::endl;
                WaitForNotification();
                if (!m_queue.empty()) {
                    // I want to execute the latest task from the queue here and cancel the rest of the tasks
                    CopyTask latest_task_to_execute = m_queue.back();
                    m_queue = {};
                    latest_task_to_execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void StopThread() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queue_mutex);
        m_running = false;
        if (m_thread.joinable()) {
            try {
                m_thread.join();
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                // Log
            }
        }
        std::cout << " Looper thread exiting " << std::endl;
    }

    void WaitForNotification() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> que_lock(m_queue_mutex);
        m_condition_variable.wait(que_lock, [this] {
            return m_trigger;
        });
        m_trigger = false;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << " -- Beginining of program -- " << std::endl;
    
    TaskQueue task_queue;
    task_queue.PushCopyTask([&task_queue](){
        std::thread t1([&] {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(70));
            std::cout << " PushCopyTask number 1 fninshed executing " << std::endl;
            task_queue.CopyTaskCompleted();
        });
    });

    task_queue.PushCopyTask([&task_queue](){
        std::thread t2([&] {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(70));
            std::cout << " PushCopyTask number 2 fninshed executing " << std::endl;
            task_queue.CopyTaskCompleted();
        });
    });

    task_queue.PushCopyTask([&task_queue](){
        std::thread t3([&] {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(70));
            std::cout << " PushCopyTask number 3 fninshed executing " << std::endl;
            task_queue.CopyTaskCompleted();
        });
    });

    task_queue.PushCopyTask([&task_queue](){
        std::thread t4([&] {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(70));
            std::cout << " PushCopyTask number 4 fninshed executing " << std::endl;
            task_queue.CopyTaskCompleted();
        });
    });

    std::cout << " -- Ending of program -- " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But above does not work. It seems like I am doing something wrong with the `condition_variable`?

How can write a tasks queue with a *simple public API* like above class `TaskQueue` has where I can pass a method to execute and it should always execute the latest method when it gets a chance.

**Dev env:**
Macos Big Sure with C++ clang compiler

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things here:

1. You're using a different mutex when setting m_triggered than with the condition variable. You need to use the same one.
2. You're not securing the acces to m_queue via mutex in the worker thread
3. PushCopyTask will never push anything to the queue. It takes the mtx, sees that the queue is empty, then executes the task and returns. Simultaneous calls will block while trying to take the mtx.
4. If only the latest q element is supposed to be executed, why use a queue at all? I suggest using std::optional instead. Then push can just overwrite it.

Comment: Lets say the `PushCopyTask` is called with a copy task that takes 30 milliseconds to return. During those 30 milliseconds if `PushCopyTask` was called 5 times by other threads then we have 5 more items waiting in the queue to be executed. Right? This is where the queue comes into play and I want to execute the last item. But you have point. I can even just have a pair of 2 items where one item is executing and the other one just gets replaced with request for new tasks?

Comment: It would be great to see some example code which deals with this kind of a problem. I now feel that this could and should be done without a queue. I just need to execute the latest task request when one task is complete. Thats it. Struggling to find a nice example for this

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. It has rung a bell in my mind :D

Comment: But the queue wont come into play at all right now. The other five threads are going to block when trying to take the mutex until the first thread unlocks it. So they will just block and complete their tasks one after another. Thats what im getting at in point 3. I'm on my phone, so i cant really whip up an example right now, ill do it tomorrow (if i remember).

Comment: No problem, good luck ;)

Comment: Well. `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(70));` is called inside an `std::thread`. It will not be async? Ah, the threads will want to join before exiting the lambda scope? Ah, my test code in the main function has an issue itself

Comment: I didnt even notice that youre creating new threads in every copy task lambda. Doesnt that defeat the whole purpose of a thread queue like this? The tasks are basically going to run simultaneously in an undefined order, because you are just creating 4 threads and letting them run. I don't know your use-case, but your lambdas should almost definitely be synchronous/blocking, otherwise the queue has no way of knowing when a task has finished.

Comment: Note that I call `task_queue.CopyTaskCompleted` in the thread to notify `TaskQueue` when a particular task is completed.

Comment: Sure, but the threads still run simultaneously and the queue is still never used. The current implementation is functionally equivalent to just starting 4 threads in Main directly. And while you are right that the queue knows when a task finishes because of CopyTaskCompleted, I don't see any reason why the queue thread should not do that work itself instead of starting a new thread and sleeping till that thread is finished.